# Infinite dimensional Vector Spaces and Bases of Quotients

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Given a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of an infinite dimensional vector space $V$, will a quotient of $V$ by a subspace $I$ necessarily have a basis? Is there a way of obtaining it using $\mathcal{B}$?

My first (naive) thought was to take some specific set of cosets from $\mathcal{B}$, but I don't think this will work, as we can lose linear independence easily. I know the Axiom of Choice gives us the existence of a basis, but I'm looking (hopefully) for something more constructive.

I don't even know whether without AoC the quotient would even be free.

**edit:**

a thought i've had is to write $I $ as the span of a set of vectors written in terms of  our basis, and then choose from $\mathcal{B}$ all the basis elements that do not appear in any of the linear combinations which span $I$. Does this work, and does it implicitly use AoC?

i.e something like let $I = \langle \sum\lambda_{ij} v_{j} : v_j \in \mathcal{B} , \ i \in I \rangle $

then set $\bar{\mathcal{B}} = \lbrace v + I \in V/I \ : v \in \mathcal{B} \ \text{ does not appear in the linear combinations  above} \rbrace $

Comment: Are you talking about Hamel basis or something like Schauder basis? If it's Hamel then its existence in $V$ already requires the axiom of choice, so there is no point getting constructive after that.

Comment: I'm not sure, I can read up on these, but $B$ is countable and every vector in $V$ has a finite expression as l.c from $B$

Comment: @Conifold: $V$ is a vector space, hence it doesn't make sense of talk about a Schauder basis. For vector spaces, there is a *unique* notion of a basis. There are more notions for Banach spaces, but Banach spaces should not be confused with their underlying vector spaces and the question is not about Banach spaces.

Comment: How would you do this in the finite-dimensional case? Your suggestion doesn't even work there: $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ but your procedure does not produce a basis of the quotient of $\mathbb R^2$ by the $x$-axis.

Comment: yeah didn't think it through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $V$ is any vector space with underlying set $S$, then it is a quotient of $K^{\oplus S}$, which has $S$ as a basis. But the existence of bases in arbitrary vector spaces is equivalent to AC (by a result by Andreas Blass).

Comment: this is annoying. thanks